# How to make An AppBar with widget in app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test

How can we make an Appbar like this which is auto adjustable ,can have this many widgets and items benwath it can be scrollable?

[image]

Comment: You can pass that to the Scaffolds [appBar property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/appBar.html).

Comment: are you talking about the back arrow and the order summary text right.

Comment: I want to fix deliver to username, change ,date button  and time button and in the app bar and the other things be scrollable after that

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Sliver App Bar [See](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html) many be